# How to stop items in Div rearranging when transitioning between sizes with toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use toggleClass to resize a div from a width of 10px to 500px on click, partly to show/hide content. The problem is, when the transition takes place the contents of the div can be seen rearanging until they eventually overflow and disapear.

Javascript (jquery 2.1.1)

```
$( "#id" ).click(function() {
$( "div.login" ).toggleClass( "closed_div" );
});
```

CSS

```
* {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition:      all 0.2s ease;
}

.div {
    height: 10px;
    width: 500px;
}

.closed_div {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="div closed_div">
    Content
</div>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? The phrase is cut. Please make a fiddle or some other live example.

Comment: Apologies, hit submit too early

Comment: This can be seen on wbrodie.com on the login icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `white-space: nowrap;` to your form

and to make it better, if I were you I would also add opacity 0 to your form and then when open opacity 1 with 0.5 sec transition delay so users will never see the form before the div is totally open.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the inputs.

```
  <form>
    <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

http://jsbin.com/hucapepofe/1/edit?html,css,js,output